# Exception handler doesn't call destructors when catching SEH exception

Tags: exception, seh

```
class ScopedShit
{
public:
    ScopedShit() {
        cout << "ScopedShit()" << endl;
    }
    ~ScopedShit() {
        cout << "~ScopedShit()" << endl;
    }
};

void foo()
{
    ScopedShit ss;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 5 / x;
}

int main()
{
    __try {
        foo();
    }
    __except(true) {
        cout << "Continuing..." << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

> ScopedShit()
>
> Continuing...

I'm reading this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2126/How-a-C-compiler-implements-exception-handling which explains:

> But before it (the exception handler) calls the catch block (it knows the address of the catch
> block from funcinfo structure, see figure 4), it must perform stack
> unwinding: cleaning up the stack frames of the functions below this
> function's frame. Cleaning of the stack frame involves nice little
> intricacy: **The exception handler must find all the local objects of
> the function alive on the frame at the time of the exception and call
> their destructors.**

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to specify [`/EHa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx) at compile time for SEH exceptions to invoke C++ destructors.

> If /EH is not specified, the compiler will catch structured and C++ exceptions, **but will not destroy C++ objects that will go out of scope as a result of the exception.**

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx) for further details.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that with this, the compiler would just insert destructor calls into the exception handler body if not present?